# How do I create a blank model object in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to build a table in template that shows the latest entry to a particular table that meets certain criteria, specifically that qor_json is not null or "". In some cases, for a given tool and context, there's *no* record that matches the criteria. Still, since I want a table, I need *something* to go there so I'm trying to pass in a blank object somehow. The part of the code below (which I'm providing all of in order to give context), is:

```
if action:
    print c, t+":", action[0].qor_json, action[0].time
    acts.append(action[0])
else:
    acts.append(None)
```

Below is the full view. What I'm trying to do is be able to display a blank table cell in cases where there's no matching object, but display an arbitrary attribute of the object if it *does*.

```
def index(request):
    t = loader.get_template('index.html')
    all_contexts   = md.Contexts.objects.all().order_by('name')
    all_tools      = md.Tools.objects.all().order_by('name')
    latest_actions = (md.Actions.objects
                      .values('tool', 'context')
                      .annotate(max_id=Max('id'))
                     )

    actions = md.Actions.objects.exclude(qor_json__isnull=True).exclude(
        qor_json__in=[""]).filter(id__in=[
        a['max_id'] for a in latest_actions
    ])

    set_of_tools = sorted(set(a.tool.name for a in actions))
    set_of_contexts = sorted(set(a.context.name for a in actions))

    names = []
    act_rows  = []

    for c in set_of_contexts:
        acts = []
        for t in set_of_tools:
            action = filter(
                lambda a: a.tool.name==t and a.context.name==c, actions)
            if action:
                names.append(action[0].time)
                acts.append(action[0])
            else:
                names.append(None)
                acts.append(None)

        act_rows.append(acts)

    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'contexts'           : all_contexts,
        'tools'              : all_tools,
        'bundles'            : zip(names, act_rows),
        'ct'                 : 25,
    })
```

This is the index.html template.

```
<table width="90%" align="center" border=1 cellpadding=10>
<tr>
  <th></th>   {# Contexts on y-axis, Tools on x-axis #}
  {% for tl in tools %}
  <th><a href="/actions?tools={{tl.name}}&ct={{ct}}">{{ tl.name }}</a></th>
  {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% for bundle in bundles %}
  <tr>
    <th><a href="/actions?context={{ bundle.0 }}&ct={{ct}}">{{ bundle.0.qor_json }}</a></th>
    {% for action in bundle.1 %}
       <td>{{ action.qor_json }}</a></td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

My thought was that if I could pass a blank Action object in, then action.qor_json would just print nothing out for the ones where there was no data, but I can't figure out how to create a blank object, because it's from a model which only pulls things from the database. Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if action:
    print c, t+":", action[0].qor_json, action[0].time
    acts.append(action[0])
else:
    acts.append(md.Actions())
```

Django convention would be to call your model `Action`, not `Actions`, by the way.